# Website external link: HTTP vs HTTPS?

Tags: http, web, https

I'm currently designing a website for a friend featuring a series of links to external social media sites (Twitter, Facebook, etc.) and in these links, I was just wondering whether it is better design to link to the HTTP or HTTPS versions of the sites.

Could linking to the HTTPS versions have any possible issues, or is there any reason why I shouldn't?

Many thanks.

Comment: I bet it would make no difference if you use http or https to link to an external resource. If your web site is using https and you link to a non-https resource then you could run into issues.

Comment: Yeah that's pretty much what I'm thinking, and the site's only http so no issues there, but there might be a particular way that's more accepted.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using protocol relative links for the external social media sites
e.g.

```
<img src="//<external website link>" alt="external source" />
```

This will work perfectly with your domain's pages with any (HTTP/HTTPS) protocol.

So if your page follows HTTPS protocol and you are pointing the external website  with HTTP protocol you would get "security warning" by the browser. The above approach will avoid this problem.